# How to configure a BLE device as a bridge to communicate from android app to a USB device?

Tags: java, android, usb, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE device (BlueMode+S42). I have attached the BLE device to a phone via a USB cable. Now I want to communicate via an app I created that sends something to the other phone.

> Android App (Bluetooth) -----> BLE device (USB cable) -----> Android phone

I can already connect and disconnect from the BLE device via the app. I can read the UUID's from the BLE Device too. So I already have the app that communicates with BLE, the problem now is to set the BLE device as a bridge to communicate from the app to the other phone.

The github project is available here (It works fine, don't look at the roughness of the code please :D): https://github.com/Dehma/BleConnectionProject.git

Edit:
Ok I did both connections and now I'm struggling with how to connect them toghether so the phones can communicate each other.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I see but i tried to find some resources about this, the only things i can find is something like "How to connect to ble device" or "How to communicate with an ble device". But nothing like how to set the ble device capable of passing info (like a string) from a bluetooth connection toa usb connection. I mean yes i can read and write from the BLE device but its only his info, not another connected device info. I know it's not an easy task or maybe it's not what people usually do so i can't find enough info about it. This is why i asked here, i'm really in need.

Comment: You should split your problem into different questions. One regarding how to communicate over USB to Android app. Another how to transfer data between app and BLE. Once you've solved these, your last thing is to combine it. Now we don't know which part you really have problems with. For example, if you don't know how to do the USB part there is no reason for asking about BLE.

Comment: My problem was how to connect both, i've alreday did the connection via ble and usb right now. But yeah you're right, I'll try to do another question maybe written better, thanks btw :D